# ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 when calling .blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding, ruby-1.9.3

I've just upgraded to Rails 3.0 (don't judge!) and Ruby 1.9.3 and have had a client able to save a string to the database that then chokes Rails when calling `.blank?` on the string.

I've found a method of heading off these invalid byte sequences at the Apache level but wondered if anyone could guide me on exactly what this user has sent in. I couldn't work it out myself. I'm guessing it's some kind of emoji? The user is authentic, i.e. they're not a script kiddie or anything like that. It looks like they were using a Samsung Android tablet.

`"sup boys what are you guys up to\xED\xA0\xBD\r\n             "`

**Update:**

Looking in the logs I've found:

`"sup boys what are you guys up to\xED\xA0\xBD\r\n             "`

Comment: Did you try looking at the raw data in mysql? It could be that the conversion is happening at the rails end. I am aware of an issue where `to_json` erroneously converts emoji to such characters. Additionally, a good place to look will be your production logs. If those are request parameters, you can get the value from there.

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing special happening to this data on the way in (other than what Rails might automatically do to it).

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggested - try looking at the entry point (production logs) and the persisted state (using raw mysql query) to see if rails is doing some conversion here. Also what's the `config.encoding` value in your application.rb file?

Answer (score 2):

Solved problem by removing invalid chars with `String#scrub` in ruby 2.1 http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-scrub. Here is backport of  `String#scrub` to ruby 1.9 and 2.0 https://github.com/hsbt/string-scrub

Comment: Interesting, I ended up using utf8-cleaner, so I posted an issue there as to whether they'd rather use String#scrub: https://github.com/singlebrook/utf8-cleaner/issues/19